# with() relation with condition retrieve all the records- Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I want to retrieve only the listed organisations but the the database return all the records.

you can see below a record should not be returned as a listed organisation I include below the code and my Model and The result I got from the database

```
      $organisations = Organisation::with(['year_status' => function ($query) use ($year_id) {
                    $query->where(['year_id' => $year_id, 'is_listed' => 1]);
                }])->get();



public function year_status()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrganisationYearStatus');
    } 

 and what I got :

11 => Organisation {#630 ▼
      #fillable: array:8 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:14 [▼
        "id" => 39
        "organisation" => "Test Organisation"
        "sector_id" => 1
        "country_id" => 1
         ]
      #original: array:14 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "year_status" => Collection {#632 ▼
          #items: []
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
```

database structure :

```
id  
organisation_id
year_id
is_listed
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your relationship is well established (Organization model hasMany year_status) and that your fields are in the visible array in the YearStatus Model.

Also, the query you're using is translated to:

```
SELECT * FROM organizations where exists 
  (select * from year_status where organizaton_id = organizations.id 
   and year_id = $year_id and is_listed = 1)
```

It doesn't fetch ALL the records existing in the database, it fetches due to the relationship + the fields you've added

Note: If you want to fetch only the organization that have OrganizationYearStatus, then you should use:

```
Organisation::whenHas('year_status' => function ($advancedWhenHas) use ($year_id) { 
  $advancedWhenHas->with(['year_status' => function ($query) use ($year_id) {
                    $query->where(['year_id' => $year_id, 'is_listed' => 1]);
}}])->get();
```

You can type out `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` to make sure your query is the one you expect it to be